# Program that first shows what is on a file and then overwrites to it ---> gives segmentation fault

Tags: c

The programs idea is to first show what is on the existing file and then overwrite a new sentence to it. But it gives segmentation fault, so could someone help me please? It shows first what is on the file, but the when the program starts to write something to it, it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
   FILE * file_ptr;
   int c;
   file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "r+");
   if(!file_ptr) printf("empty file\n");

   while(1)
   {
      c = fgetc(file_ptr);
      if( feof(file_ptr) )
      {
          break;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
    printf("\n");

   printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
   gets(c);
   fprintf(file_ptr,"%s",c);

   fclose(file_ptr);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: even a empty file could be refferenced by a non NULL fp, as it at least vontains a EOF. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Your problem is at `gets(c)`.

Comment: Why not use the returned value from `fgetc` to see if you're at the end of the file (or an error occurred)? And why not put it in the loop condition? Like e.g. `while ((c ? fgetc(file_ptr)) != EOF) { printf(...); }`

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems: The first and what's causing the crash is that you pass an *integer* to `gets`, when it wants a character buffer to fill in. You have the same problem in the next line where you print the integer as a string.

The second problem is that you're using `gets` to start with, as it's unsafe, long obsoleted and even removed from the latest C standard.

Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, and pass it a proper buffer (i.e. an array of `char`).

Answer (score 1):

`gets` wants a string (not an `int`), also note that `gets` is deprecated in C99 and removed in C11.

Suggested code:

```
char s[100];
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
    fprintf(file_ptr, "%s", s);
}
```